# How to show search results no same

Tags: django-templates, django-forms

I am new to Django, and want to do the following

I have a form that takes two inputs, processes and forwards the results to another page.
I want to display the results in the same page with form page included.

How can I do that in Django?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the data in the session after the POST, and pull it out of the session on the other page.